# Is this still follow Dependency Inversion Principle when implement multiple interface?

Tags: java, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

sorry for the long question and also my English.

I'm reading [an article about DIP](https://stackify.com/dependency-inversion-principle/). I will summarize the code in here.

```
interface CoffeeMachine() {
    void brewFilterCoffee();
}

interface EspressoMachine() {
    void brewEspressoCoffee();
}
```

They create two different CoffeeMachine. BasicCoffeeMachine and PremiumCoffeeMachine. **They both have the same feature is brewFilterCoffee();** so they put it on the **CoffeeMachine** interface

```
class BasicCoffeeMachine implements CoffeeMachine {
    @Override
    void brewFilterCoffee() {
        System.out.println("brewing filter coffee...");
    }
}

// this one can make Espresso
class PremiumCoffeeMachine implements CoffeeMachine, EspressoMachine {
    @Override
    void brewFilterCoffee() {
        System.out.println("brewing filter coffee but in premium way...");
    }

    @Override
    void brewEspressoCoffee() {
        System.out.println("brewing espresso coffee...");
    }
}
```

When they create **CoffeeApp**, it accepts **CoffeeMachine** interface in the constructor and uses it to **prepareCoffee()**

```
class CoffeeApp {
    CoffeeMachine machine;
    
    public CoffeeApp(CoffeeMachine machine) {
        this.machine = machine;
    }
    
    public void prepareCoffee() {
        machine.brewFilterCoffee();
    }
}
```

In the Main class.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PremiumCoffeeMachine premiumCoffeeMachine = new PremiumCoffeeMachine();
        CoffeeApp app = new CoffeeApp(premiumCoffeeMachine);

        app.brewFilterCoffee();
    }
}
```

I left confused here because they didn't mention how they use **brewEspressoCoffee()** in CoffeeApp.
So I go ahead and modify CoffeeApp like this:

```
class CoffeeApp {
    public void prepareFilterCoffee(CoffeeMachine machine) {
        machine.brewFilterCoffee();
    }
    
    public void prepareEspressoCoffee(EspressoMachine machine) {
        machine.brewEspressoCoffee();
    }
}
```

In the Main class, if I want to **brewEspressoCoffee()**, I just create an instance that implements **EspressoMachine**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PremiumCoffeeMachine premiumCoffeeMachine = new PremiumCoffeeMachine();
        CoffeeApp app = new CoffeeApp();

        app.brewEspressoCoffee(premiumCoffeeMachine);
    }
}
```

Is this still the following DIP? And is there any better way to approach rather than this example? Any example would be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: @Fildor don't confuse DI (Dependency Injection) with DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle), DIP doesn't talk about injection, but simply about [using an abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle#Dependency_inversion_pattern) (e.g. an `interface` like `CoffeeMachine`) instead of the actual implementation (e.g. `BasicCoffeeMachine`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Lino So am I following DIP correctly?

Comment: @ABC I would say so, as `CoffeApp` doesn't rely on the implementation (i.e. the `class`), but solely on the abstraction (i.e. the `interface`)

Comment: @Lino which I mentioned ... _"and with dependencies to concrete classes on top"_.

Comment: @Lino ... but I was wrong. Confused the interfaces for the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've captured the essence of the DIP, which is that you can *always* insert an interface to invert the direction of a dependency.

Beyond just following the DIP, there is also the principle of *Information Hiding* to consider here. We often think of IH as applied to data, but it applies to dependencies as well.

In the original `CoffeeApp`, the client (customer) has no dependency on `EspressoMachine` and an indirect (transitive) dependency on `CoffeeMachine`. In the modified `CoffeeApp`, the client has direct dependencies on both Machine interfaces.

These dependencies are on abstractions, so the DIP is satisfied; but it begs the question, if `CoffeeApp` exposes its dependencies to its clients, then what is its purpose? Clients can invoke those dependencies directly. By passing on its dependencies, the `CoffeeApp` becomes useless.